# Move Bar To Bottom (2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

I'm trying to figure out how to move the 3D view header to the bottom.  It used to be at the bottom by default in version 2.79, but now it's the other way around.  Could someone show me how to move it?

[image: MoveToBottom]

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the left side of the header where the menu entries are and select *Flip to bottom*

[image]

Comment: where you able to right click anywhere on the bar for it to work?

Comment: @RBlong2us no on the left side.

Comment: interesting, It only lets you select the bar on the far left or right.  Must be so that it prevents you from accidentally clicking the bar.

Comment: well, thanks for the answer!

Comment: figured out that it isn't a matter of clicking the left side or right, but just clicking near the buttons on the header. check my answer edit

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the answer.  You have to right-click near the buttons on the header.  Unlike the older version, the header only consists of buttons; there is no colored background for you to click on.  It's transparent.  So, in order to actually click the header, you have to right-click near the buttons.